# Re-trigger Github OAuth in Salesforce DevOps Center

Tags: github, oauth, salesforce, devops

I have finally set up Salesforce DevOps Center in production and thought that I had mistakenly authed with my personal Github account when I wanted to auth with my organizations Github account. So, I deleted the OAuth App from my personal account thinking that I could re-auth with the companies account. Instead, I run into DevOps Center just telling me that it cannot find the org or a repository in the org when trying to create a pipeline instead of re-triggering the auth with Github portion.

Is there a way to re-trigger that OAuth manually? Do I need to delete a cache somewhere in Salesforce that is keeping that OAuth record?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late.. but for anyone that comes here:
[Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.devops_center_connect_diff_github_acct.htm&type=5) says that you should find the named credential "DevOps Center GitHub" in Named Credentials setting. Then Under External Data User Authentications, delete the record for the affected user